# Impact of variables in model using XGBoost in R

Tags: r, xgboost

I have a model using medical data in R that I have created using XGBoost.  I can tell feature importance and the top feature is BMI.  However, I do not know how to tell how this impacts the model--it a binary outcome of hemorrhage, so does a lower or higher BMI cause the patient to be classified as being at risk for hemorrhage.  Does anyone know how to be able to find this out?  Thank you!

Comment: You might want to look into something like [iml](https://github.com/christophM/iml), which provides a suite of model agnostic machine learning interpretability techniques

Comment: Dalex has a breakdown function for specific cases and a Ceteris Paribus for general predictions